# console.log return webElement object instead of value

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, asynchronous, async-await, selenium-chromedriver

I have simple code which stopped print value and return this instead. Any clue what's wrong?

My code:

```
async function openWiki() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
    await driver.get("https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:random");
    let title = await driver.findElement(By.id("firstHeading"));
    console.log(title);
}

openWiki();
```

end it wrote to terminal:

```
WebElement {
  driver_: Driver {
    session_: Promise { [Session] },
    executor_: Executor { customCommands_: [Map], log_: [Logger], w3c: true },
    fileDetector_: null,
    onQuit_: [Function: onQuit],
    authenticatorId_: null,
    pinnedScripts_: {}
  },
  id_: Promise { '50117978-c479-43d4-aced-033f6b2799fc' }
}
```

I expect value written to the console. When only returning title, there is no error. I tried title.getText(), I got `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: Your `openWiki()` function is `async`, but you call it without `await`.

Comment: @Pointy I cannot simply call await openWiki() due to await is only valid in async function. I have seen few tutorials and they also used simply openWiki() call. So it has to be used in some different way in this case?

Comment: If you don't want to use `await` you get a Promise instance. You can use `.then()` to arrange a callback when the Promise is resolved.

Comment: @pointy but how should be await used? I am able to use it with then as: openWiki().then(title=>console.log(title)); But is there different way using await?

Comment: You can use an anonymous `async` wrapper function and call it immediately.

Comment: `console.log(await title.getText());`

Comment: what hoangdv said. You're logging the whole element not just the text